# Handling NumLock on OS X with Karabiner

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard, desktop-customization

I'm trying to remap the numpad keys on Mac OS (El Capitan) with **Karabiner** to work similarly as in Windows (as I'm using a Windows keyboard with my Mac).

I added the following line to enable toggling **NumLock**:

```
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::KEYPAD_CLEAR, KeyCode::VK_IOHIKEYBOARD_TOGGLE_NUMLOCK</autogen>
```

It works fine, but I can't find a way to query whether the NumLock is on or off. When it's turned off I'd like to use the numeric keys for jumping in the text editor (1 - End, 2 - Down, 3 - Page Down, etc.), when it's on I'd like to use them to type digits with it (retain the default behavior).
Right now the key mappings look like this:

```
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::KEYPAD_1, KeyCode::CURSOR_RIGHT, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L</autogen>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::KEYPAD_2, KeyCode::CURSOR_DOWN</autogen>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::KEYPAD_3, KeyCode::PAGEDOWN, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L</autogen>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::KEYPAD_4, KeyCode::CURSOR_LEFT</autogen> 

etc...
```

But this doesn't take it into account whether the NumLock is enabled or not. Is there any way to get that info with Karabiner? (there's no ModifierFlag value for it). I only need to make this work on my Windows keyboard.

Comment: OS X doesn't have a num lock at all. The Clear key will work in Windows as num lock, but there's no equivalent in OS X. The 10-key pad is always numbers, unless you invoke mouse-keys, in which case it becomes cursor & mouse-click. Fn/arrow keys are the usual alternative to home/end etc. though afaik, they're interpreted at the keyboard, not at the OS.

Comment: That is exactly why I use Karabiner. I can remap the numeric keys to work like they work on Windows (moving the cursor, by remapping them Fn+arrow combinations). I can also enable toggling the Num Lock on OX X. That's not the problem. I only want to do that when the Num Lock is turned off, and while I can toggle it with Karabiner, I can't find the way to ask the Num Lock status from the system. I only need to make this work on my Windows keyboard.

Comment: OS X just doesn't have a num lock, so I'm not sure how you can either toggle it or request its status. It must be an internal function of Karabiner